# Gradle task not executed if added as a dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have two gradle tasks in my `build.gradle` file, one to archive a folder and another to push it to a remote server.

```
task tarTask(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'tar', '-czf', 'javadocs.tgz', 'javadocs/'
}
```

If I execute tarTask alone with `gradle tarTask` and with the `publish` task commented out,  the build succeeds. 
I am using this task as a dependency in the publish task.

```
task publish(dependsOn: tarTask) {
    ssh.run {
        settings {
            knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
            fileTransfer = 'scp'
        }

        session(remotes.webServer) {
            from: 'javadocs.tgz', into: 'publishingHouse/'
        }
    }
}
```

But when i execute `gradle publish` it fails saying that it is not able to find the tgz file which should have been created if the previous task is executed.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: javadocs.tgz

Being new to gradle i am not really sure what I am missing here. Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: what does 'javadocs/' mean in tar task? does it mean that tar is saved in that folder? maybe you should use  'javadocs/javadocs.tgz' in publish task?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker `javadocs/` is just the name of the folder to archive. So, it takes `javadocs` folder and archives it as `javadocs.tgz`. So, from and into in the publish task is fine. It works fine if the file exists.

Comment: when you run gradle publish, do you see console message that tarTask is executed or it is just skipped?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, It doesn't show anything. But when I add print statements before and after the `commandLine` statement, I can see that they are both printed but still the tar file doesn't get created.

Comment: println statements are executed on configuration phase, they are printed every time build.gradle is 'compiled' by gradle. anyway, seems that task execution is skipped

Comment: Okay. How can I make gradle not skip it? And why is it skipping it?

Comment: some tasks can be skipped if their inputs didn't change since last invocation. i'm not sure that's your case. anyway, let's try it with flag --rerun-tasks. like gradle publish --rerun-tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the reason is within the phase when tasks are executed. `tarTask` is configured at the configuration phase and will be executed at the execution phase.

And at the same time `publish` task doesn't have any behavior to execute at the execution phase, but has `ssh.run` to be executed during configuration.

This mean, that when you run `gradle publish` your logic to copy tar-archive is executed at the configuration phase, while tar-archive is not yet exists (it will be created later at the execution phase).

To make a copy execution at the execution phase you can simply add `<<` to the `publish` task declaration as follows:

```
task publish(dependsOn: tarTask) << {
    ssh.run {
        settings {
            knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
            fileTransfer = 'scp'
        }

        session(remotes.webServer) {
            from: 'javadocs.tgz', into: 'publishingHouse/'
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that `<<` is the same as `doLast` and the closure will be excuted at the execution phase. You can read about Gradle build lifecycle [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)

Comment: @Stanislav, How did you know that `ssh.run` will happen at configuration phase? Is it the default behavior or is that because of something I have in the code?

Comment: it's because `ssh.run` causes execution immediately and then it's placed within task closure without `<<` it's getting called during configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I looked at several articles and have to come to a similar conclusion but was not able to understand why ssh.run was not happening during the execution phase.

Comment: This is due to `ssh.run` is not a task, but an exact actionm which is executed when it's called from your code.